# How to prevent duplicate IDS in foreach statement PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a foreach that stores data to a datebase. The only problem am having is with the generated IDS. Each added item into database should have it's own unique fileID.

```
   foreach ($videos['items'] as $videoResult) {
     **$musicThis = Music::Where('file', '=', $videoResult['id']->videoId)->get();**
     if(count($musicThis) < 1) {
     $music_id = substr(md5(time()+$videoResult['snippet']['title']), 0, 11);
     $music = new Music;
     $music->filename = $videoResult['snippet']['title'];
     $music->fileDesc = $videoResult['snippet']['description'];
     **$music->fileID = $music_id;**
     $music->save();
     }
    }
```

When this is executed, my database ends up with the same fileID, which is not what I want. How can I do this right?

Comment: Do you need to be able to regenerate it ? If not, why not use a uuid4? see: https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid

Comment: Even with uuid, won't I still be generating the random string?

Comment: Highly unlikely with version 4 :) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. `for there to be a one in a billion chance of duplication, 103 trillion version 4 UUIDs must be generated.` I doubt you'll ever get there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler test case:

```
var_dump(1+"foo", 1+"bar");
```

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
int(1)
int(1)
```

You may want to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) rather than sum.

In any case, the overall logic is pretty confusing. `time()` has a 1-second resolution so it'll sometimes clash on duplicate titles, some times not.

Comment: Ah, I did miss that one. Still, given that the `time()` and the title are unique when generating the md5 hash, the substr of 11 chars of that hash has a reasonable chance of collisions. I would suggest dropping the md5 altogether for something more random?

Comment: @Robert Certainly, writing your own cryptography is rarely a good idea. If in this path, I'd just generate random letters (using the complete alphabet) or let the database assign consecutive integers.

Comment: BTW, `16^11` is `17,592,186,044,416`.

Comment: Reasonable as in compared to using uuid4. Yes, theoretically you'll have the 16^11 options, but there is a higher chance of collisions compared to other options. Why take that risk at all?